# SVG/Layer not working in IE and Webkit, Firefox is fine though

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm completely stuck, i really need help guys!

Below are my snippets, which i've trimmed down as much as possible and edited a bit to show correctly on jsfiddle.
Also here is the JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/oqfdfart/9/

What i need: a transparent half circle in my header that lets through my bg image, but also has a border. I managed to do this with 2 SVG's.

However only firefox shows everything fine, but all other browsers don't.

I'm eternally grateful for any help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var $myCarousel = $('#myCarousel');

  function setCaptTotalheight(captid, maxheight) {

    setTimeout(function() {

      sliderheight = $('#slideimg' + captid).height();
      //alert(sliderheight);
      if (sliderheight > 0) {

        if (sliderheight > maxheight) {
          useheight = maxheight;
        } else {
          useheight = sliderheight;
        }

        $('.container-carousel').attr('style', 'height:' + useheight + 'px;padding:0px; overflow:hidden;');
        $('.header-carousel').attr('style', 'height:' + useheight + 'px; overflow:hidden;');
        $('#slide' + captid).attr('style', 'height:' + useheight + 'px;');

      }

    }, 5);

  }


  function setCaptheight(captid, maxheight) {}


  var $navElemsId = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').attr('data-id');
  var $navElemsCenter = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').attr('data-center');
  var $navElemsMaxHeight = $myCarousel.find('.item:first').attr('data-maxheight');

  if ($navElemsCenter == 1) {
    setCaptTotalheight($navElemsId, $navElemsMaxHeight);
    setCaptheight($navElemsId, $navElemsMaxHeight);
  }

  if ($navElemsCenter == 2) {
    setCaptTotalheight($navElemsId, $navElemsMaxHeight);
  }


});
```

```css
@import url( 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css' );
@import url( 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );

body{
    background: #eee;
}

#headeroverlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel {
    background: url(http://placehold.it/230x50) no-repeat 50% 95%;
}

#myCarousel .item {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #942994;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    mask: url(#mask);
}

.nopadding {
    padding: 0;
}

#headeroverlay {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    height: 223px;
    z-index: auto;
}

#innercircle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="mp-pusher maincontainer maincontainer-602" id="mp-pusher" style="position:inherit">

<div class="container-fluid container-fluid-header header-container-above-menu container-carousel" style="height:auto; max-height:499px; overflow:hidden; padding:0px;"><!-- start carousel -->

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel carousel-fade slide myCarousel-slide" style="height:auto; max-height:499px; overflow:hidden">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div id="slide2" class="item active" data-navpos="" data-navposarrow="" data-center="1" data-maxheight="499" data-id="2"  style=""><img id="slideimg2" class="logofull img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/1920x499" /></div>
    </div>
</div>

<section id="headeroverlay" class="headeroverlay">

<svg width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
        #inner {
        stroke: #942994;
        stroke-width: 5;
        fill-opacity: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        }
        ]]></style>
        <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
            <circle id="c1" cx="50%" cy="105%" r="180" fill="#000"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50" mask="url(#mask)" fill-opacity="0"/>
</svg>
<svg id="innercircle" width="100%" height="100%" x="0" y="0">
    <circle id="inner" x="0" y="0" cx="50%" cy="105%" r="181" fill="#fff" />
</svg>

</section>

</div>
```

Comment: Most browsers don't allow SVG effects such as mask to be applied to html content such as a div element. Firefox is an exception.

Comment: I see, that really explains a lot! Do you know of any way i might still be able to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Either see if you can do it with CSS effects such as a CSS mask (rather than an SVG mask). Or do more in SVG i.e. apply the SVG effect to SVG content and make the SVG content render as the HTML content would have done.

Comment: Awesome, following your suggestions i have now hidden my header and replaced it with an SVG containing my header image. However i'm now struggling with the viewbox to get the header size and position the same as my original header image. This is my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oqfdfart/10/  Any thoughts?

Comment: Extra info: in my case i get the viewbox coordinates "0 0 911 219" to sorta work (doesn't fill 100% width though) but only on my specific screen size

Comment: I imagine you want to set preserveAspectRatio to something appropriate for your use case.